# Order by calculated fields in Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following fields in one of my entities: `price(decimal)`, `promo(boolean)`, and `promoPrice(decimal)` and I want to get query with order by real price, so I need to create query like this one:

```
SELECT *, (!promo*price + promo*promo_price) as real_price 
FROM `product` ORDER BY real_price ASC
```

Is there any way to do it with QueryBuilder or maybe I need to use some native methods?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html

Comment: @Alex.Barylski Thx, post updated.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, then remove it from your question and finally accept your answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->addSelect('CASE WHEN p.promo = :value THEN p.promoPrice ELSE p.price END AS HIDDEN realPrice')
    ->setParameter('value', true)
    ->orderBy('realPrice', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();
```